# Unable to show the activity indicator iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview, activity-indicator

I can't get to display the activity spinner on UIWebView
Need to show UIActivityIndicatorView while the page is being loaded.
UIActivityIndicatorView is declared but it's never shown on the UIWebView

Please assist.
The code is as follows :

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "MyScreen"
#import "Reachability.h"

@interface MyScreen ()
@end

@implementation MyScreen
{;
    UIView *loadingView;
}

@synthesize gotoMainMenu;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    loadingView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 400, 80, 80)];
    loadingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0. alpha:0.6];
    loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activityView.center = CGPointMake(loadingView.frame.size.width / 2.0, 35);
    [activityView startAnimating];
    activityView.tag = 100;
    [loadingView addSubview:activityView];

    UILabel* lblLoading = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 48, 80, 30)];
    lblLoading.text = @"Loading...";
    lblLoading.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lblLoading.font = [UIFont fontWithName:lblLoading.font.fontName size:15];
    lblLoading.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [loadingView addSubview:lblLoading];

    [self.view addSubview:loadingView];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:true];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=false;
    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (netStatus != NotReachable)
    {
        NSLog(@"Network is Available");
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Error" message:@"Please check internet connectivity!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil , nil];
        [alertView show];
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}

-(id) init
{
    if([super init])
    {
        webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, -64.00, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height+64.0)];
        webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
        webView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://theURL/"];
        req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
        NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:5.0];
        [webView loadRequest:theRequest];
        [webView loadRequest:req];
        [self.view addSubview:webView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [loadingView setHidden:YES];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [loadingView setHidden:NO];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use "self.view" in your init function. When you use it, the view is loaded and viewDidLoad will be invoked before you add webView. So you webView is added after your loading view.

Just try to move this line:

```
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

After:

```
[self.view addSubview:loadingView];
```